# Does MediatR walk all classes in the project looking for matches?

Tags: asp.net-core, mediatr

There are two parts to this question. First I am going to explain what I think is happening? And then second, in that explanation, I want to verify how it is finding a class it needs.

This is from Nick Chapsas' program [Write cleaner APIs in .NET 7 with MediatR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euUg_IHo7-s).

This code handles a request using MediatR as follows.

n program.cs it has:

```
app.MediateGet<ExampleRequest>("example/{name}");
```

which is called via the extension function:

```
public static WebApplication MediateGet<TRequest>(
    this WebApplication app,
    string template) where TRequest : IHttpRequest
{
    app.MapGet(template, async (IMediator mediator,
        [AsParameters] TRequest request) => await mediator.Send(request));
    return app;
}
```

where IHttpRequest is defined as:

```
public interface IHttpRequest : IRequest<IResult>
{
}
```

So what has occurred from all this is me have an app.MapGet() call for the url "example/{name}" and it will be handles by MediatR.

ExampleRequest.cs is a POCO containing the URL parameters, etc.

The handler must implement the interface IRequestHandler<ExampleRequest, IResult>. When that url is requested, it will instantiate the appropiate class and call its Handle() method passing in the ExampleRequest and getting a Task returned.

**Question 1:** Is that correct?

There is the following class in the program that is a handler that implements the require interface. And it is called by MediatR.

```
public class ExampleHandler : IRequestHandler<ExampleRequest, IResult>
{
    private readonly GuidService _guidService;

    public ExampleHandler(GuidService guidService)
    {
        _guidService = guidService;
    }

    public async Task<IResult> Handle(
        ExampleRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10, cancellationToken);
        return Results.Ok(new
        {
            message = $"The age was: {request.Age} and the name was: {request.Name}",
            requestGuid = request.GuidService.Id,
            ctorGuid = _guidService.Id
        });
    }
}
```

**Question 2a:** How does MediatR find this class? It is not passed to anything or registered with anything. Does MediatR scan all classes looking for a match?

**Question 2b:** And if so, what if there are two matches?

**Question 2c:** Also if so, is there a way to register handler classes to speed up finding them and avoid duplicate matches?

Comment: You use your `services.AddMediatR(<AssemblyNameOrType here>)` there to register MediatR. It will just scan that assembly for all types implementing and register it with the Dependency Injection system for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Effectively, yes. The idea is that you're tying individual endpoint operations to a responsible request/response handler, for which a concrete implementation class may implement one or several; the endpoint is abstracted from that responsibility and just needs to know about it's own required input and output pair, resolution is handled by MediatR.

**2a.** Reflection and assembly scanning. The registration process asks for assemblies to scan, and the MediatR library will locate and attempt to register classes that fulfill its interfaces

https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Registration/ServiceRegistrar.cs

> MediatR supports Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
> directly. To register various MediatR services and handlers:
>
> services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
> cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining()); or with an
> assembly:
>
> services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
> cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Startup).Assembly));
>
> This registers:
>
> - IMediator as transient
> - ISender as transient
> - IPublisher as transient
> - IRequestHandler<,> concrete implementations as transient
> - IRequestHandler<> concrete implementations as transient
> - INotificationHandler<> concrete implementations as transient
> - IStreamRequestHandler<> concrete implementations as transient
> - IRequestPreProcessor<> concrete implementations as transient
> - IRequestPostProcessor<,> concrete implementations as transient
> - IRequestExceptionHandler<,,> concrete implementations as transient
> - IRequestExceptionAction<,>) concrete implementations as transient
>
> This also registers open generic implementations for:
>
> - INotificationHandler<>
> - IRequestPreProcessor<>
> - IRequestPostProcessor<,>
> - IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>
> - IRequestExceptionAction<,>

**2b.** Which takes precedence depends on how you register them, but MediatR will only resolve one IRequestHandler for a given type. The assembly scanner will register the first located handler and will skip any additional ones it finds. If you manually register multiple, it will use the last registered.

**2c.** Yes. You do not have to use the automated assembly scanning via the registration extensions to register MediatR; you can manually register the implementations of IMediator, ISender, and IPublisher yourself, and then selectively register all of your various handlers manually into the IoC container.